# Tailwind elements carousel two column content with image

Tags: carousel, tailwind-css, laravel-9

I modify the tailwind elements carousel with two columns left column with content and a right column with image. All functionality is correct but the problem is responsivity.
How can I modify this carousel so that I change the resolution to md or sm I get columns vertical?

I tried to do flex flex-row and when i change the resolution to md or sm to be flex flex-col and nothing changed the same with grid grid-cols-2 and after changing to md and sm to grid-cols-1

This is my code

```html
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide relative" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators absolute right-0 bottom-0 left-0 flex justify-center p-0 mb-4">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide-to="0"
            class="active"
            aria-current="true"
            aria-label="Slide 1"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide-to="1"
            aria-label="Slide 2"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide-to="2"
            aria-label="Slide 3"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner relative w-full overflow-hidden">
          <div class="carousel-item active relative float-left w-full">
            <img
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(15).jpg"
              class="block w-1/4 h-96 float-right mr-80"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="carousel-caption hidden md:block absolute text-left h-96 ">
                <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl lg:text-6xl text-blue-900 leading-tight font-poppins pb-4 ">SOME TEXT</h1>
              <p class="text-gray-500">Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item relative float-left w-full">
            <img
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(22).jpg"
              class="block w-1/4 h-96 float-right mr-80"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="carousel-caption hidden md:block absolute text-left h-96">
                <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl lg:text-6xl text-blue-900 leading-tight font-poppins pb-4">SOME TEXT 1</h1>
              <p  class="text-gray-500">Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item relative float-left w-full">
            <img
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(23).jpg"
              class="block w-1/4 h-96 float-right mr-80"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="carousel-caption hidden md:block absolute text-left h-96">
                <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl lg:text-6xl text-blue-900 leading-tight font-poppins pb-4">SOME TEXT 2</h1>
              <p  class="text-gray-500">Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev absolute top-0 bottom-0 flex items-center justify-center p-0 text-center border-0 hover:outline-none hover:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:no-underline left-0 text-black"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon inline-block bg-no-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next absolute top-0 bottom-0 flex items-center justify-center p-0 text-center border-0 hover:outline-none hover:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:no-underline right-0 text-black"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon inline-block bg-no-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
</div>
```